# Windows Slow Down: high ram and CPU usage by miscellaneous windows process

Tags: windows-10, memory, performance, process, task-manager

I recently experienced the slowdown of my windows 10 desktop pc.
Issue - slow Windows due to mysterious process

**DESCRIPTION:**

I checked the task manager for finding reason of slowdown. There I saw a miscellaneous or mysterious windows process taking high ram about 4 GB (I have 8 GB RAM) and 30% CPU (i5-7th gen., 4 cores). I am attaching pictures of this with its properties in the question.

task manager screenshot
[image]

General Properties of process
[image]

Details in properties of process
[image]

**WHAT I DID:**
I have tried to end the task manually but it says, "*if you do this then windows will either shutdown or become unstable and i will lose all my unsaved data.*"

Some more details:
I have recently installed anaconda and android studio but they were not running at that time.

**QUESTION:**

My question is why it is happening and what is its solution?

Comment: Seems that your svchost processes are going haywire. Here's a "fix" you can try. If it doesn't bring things back to normal, you can easily undo it, no risk: open Regedit (as admin, it's preferable) and navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control. There, in the right pane, should be an entry named SvcHostSplitThresholdInKB (if not, create a DWORD by that name by right-clicking in the empty space, then new > DWORD). Double-click on this entry and change the value to 8388608. That's slightly over your installed RAM, and will prevent svchost from multiplying processes. Restart.

Comment: can you please write in steps to be more clear

Answer (score -1):

Try to disable Windows push to install service (from services.msc) [image]

Steps:
From Windows menu type **services.msc** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> then type **services.msc** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>).
In the opened window scroll down and find "**Windows Push Notifications System Service**" and "**Windows PushToInstall Service**".
Double click on each of them and change **Startup Type** = *Disabled*, then press OK.
Restart your computer.

Comment: Can you please explain me this more clearly?

Comment: From Windows menu type services.msc and press Enter (or press Win+R then type services.msc and press Enter).
In the opened window scroll down and find "Windows Push Notifications System Service" and "Windows PushToInstall Service".
Double click on each of them and change Startup Type = Disabled, then press OK.
Then restart your computer.